# Request using BackgroundWorker never seems to complete

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I created a Loading Window for my Login form, and I use BackgroundWorker to make a smooth Loading animation, but if I use `ShowDialog()` insted of `Show()`, the Loading Window stays on screen, and the program does nothing. What's causing this?

Here I invoke the BackgroundWorker and I show the Loading page:

```
private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    loadscr.Show();
    LoginBV.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

and here I close the Loading Window:

```
private void LoginBV_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    loadscr.Close();
    //and show the MainWindow, etc.
}
```

The DoWork(BackgroundWorker) code:

```
    private void LoginBV_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        NameValueCollection POST = new NameValueCollection();
        POST["username"] = ipbUN.Text;
        POST["password"] = ipbPASS.Text;
        POST["pin"] = ipbPIN.Text;
        POST["csoport"] = "user";

        var action = Program.startPOST<DataObj>("http://localhost/system/winapi.php?do=userlogin", POST);

        finish["sessionkey"] = action.sessionkey;
        finish["status"] = Convert.ToString(action.status);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [MSDN article on `ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx).

> "You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your
>   application. When this method is called, the code following it is not
>   executed until after the dialog box is closed."

Using modal dialogs (`ShowDialog`) stops the execution of the code following it until something/someone dismisses the dialog. It "pauses" your program. The background worker is never run because you start it after calling `ShowDialog`.

Comment: Indeed, I swapped the 2 lines and now it works just fine, thank you.